# How to use Bing Map cache in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, bing-maps

How can i use the bing map cache mode in WinRT.

I already used `Cachemode="BitmapCache"`, but this doesn't work ! after using that, the Map just disappears from the view.

This solution works fine with Windows Phone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is currently disabled. The map tiles are dynamically generated. If caching was enabled and a change happened to the data it's possible that you would end up with two tiles with data that doesn't line up.

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there any way to avoid the memory leak caused by the bing map !!

Comment: Not really. You should only ever load the map once in your application and reuse it across pages if needed.

Comment: How can i do this! the map is loaded eveytime i acess the page even if i return from another page !

Comment: You have to load the map on the main page, create a static variable to access the map, and then when your sub-page loads reposition & resize the map as needed.

Comment: @rbrundritt great tip on using the map Control as a static with multiple pages it's an interesting approach as I use multiple map controls on different pages. But how would you handle `MapElements` for different views like a `Polyline` on the MainPage and `Pushpins` on the SecondPage using a static map?. Could you please explain it a little bit or share a piece of code or sample project. It'll be of great help.